# Convert Console application to Website in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have a console application that reads an XML file and outputs everything into a console.
I need to convert this application to output the data on an .aspx page.

This is the code

```
 // Declare XmlTextReader.
        XmlTextReader r = new XmlTextReader("../../persons.xml");

        while (r.Read())
        {
            switch (r.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    if (r.Name == "Persons")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("<table>");
                        Console.WriteLine("    <tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Gender</th> <th>Age</th> </tr>");
                    }
                    else if (r.Name == "Person")
                    {
                        Console.Write("    <tr> ");
                    }
                    else if (r.Name == "Name" ||
                             r.Name == "Gender" || r.Name == "Age")
                    {
                        Console.Write("<td>");
                    }
                    break;

                case XmlNodeType.Text:
                    Console.Write(r.Value);
                    break;

                case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                    if (r.Name == "Persons")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("</table>\n");
                    }
                    else if (r.Name == "Person")
                    {
                        Console.Write("</tr>\n");
                    }
                    else if (r.Name == "Name" ||
                             r.Name == "Gender" || r.Name == "Age")
                    {
                        Console.Write(">/td> ");
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
```

I found a lot of examples on how to read XML using ASP.NET but unfortunately i need to this the hard way.

Comment: You could change console to response for the simplest way.

Comment: I'm new to this so if you could explain further it will really help. What do I do after changing  console to response?

Comment: you need to spend a bit of time reading up on web apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add a literal control on your .aspx page like this:

```
<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" />
```

Then modify the code like so:

```
// Declare XmlTextReader.
XmlTextReader r = new XmlTextReader("../../persons.xml");

//Add this stringBuilder
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

while (r.Read())
{
    switch (r.NodeType)
    {
        case XmlNodeType.Element:
            if (r.Name == "Persons")
            {
                sb.Append("<table>");
                sb.Append("    <tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Gender</th> <th>Age</th> </tr>");
            }
            else if (r.Name == "Person")
            {
                sb.Append("    <tr> ");
            }
            else if (r.Name == "Name" ||
                     r.Name == "Gender" || r.Name == "Age")
            {
                sb.Append("<td>");
            }
            break;
       case XmlNodeType.Text:
            sb.Append(r.Value);
            break;
       case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
            if (r.Name == "Persons")
            {
                sb.Append("</table>\n");
            }
            else if (r.Name == "Person")
            {
                sb.Append("</tr>\n");
            }
            else if (r.Name == "Name" ||
                     r.Name == "Gender" || r.Name == "Age")
            {
                sb.Append(">/td> ");
            }
            break;
    }
}

//Add the result value to a literal control on the aspx page
Literal1.Text=sb.ToString();
```

cheers

Comment: This is what I was thinking too. I will try and let you know. Thanks

Comment: It does work! I just have to figure out where I have issues on my original code because my table is not showing right.

Comment: It may be because the final sb.Append has invalid html. Change the >/td> to </td>.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider few alternatives

1. Override the default output of Console

   StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
   Console.SetOut(sw);

All the output would be stored in sw variable

1. Use XSLT (The best option)